# Internal error: Unexpected GitHub remote configuration: 'theirs'

Tags: r, git, github, git-remote

I am currently working on a collaborative R-project, and after I forked the repository, I made a couple of changes and wanted to push them. However, when I tried to push it in the Rstudio, it raised the following error.

```
Internal error: Unexpected GitHub remote configuration: 'theirs'
```

To push the commits, I've used the following code :

```
pr_push()
```

Here are some context:

```
git remote -v

origin https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.git (push)
```

The code I used to fork the original repository.

```
library(usethis)  
create_from_github("PPBDS/primer",   
                    fork = TRUE,   
                    destdir = "/mydest/",   
                    protocol = "https")
```

The branch I've created to work on:

```
> pr_init(branch ='Python.v')
√ Pulling changes from 'origin/master'
√ Creating and switching to local branch 'Python.v'
```

I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That error appears to originate in [`usethis::check_ours_or_fork`](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/blob/master/R/utils-github.R#L629) (which, while not exported, is called from `usethis::pr_push`). Lacking any context, that's all I can tell you; it would help if you showed some code and/or some github configuration ... really, anything more than just the error with no other lead-in.

Comment: Context that might be useful: your repo, the upstream repo; the git commands and/or R functions you used to fork, pull, and attempt to push; the output from `git remotes -v` on the cli. That's a good starting point, perhaps there will need to be more if none of that has gems.

Comment: what information do you want me to provide? just let me know so i can add it .

Comment: @r2evans I've tried to add as much context as I can.

Comment: PS: I could copy the code I've written and make the request from the Github website, but in the long-term, that seems like a daunting option.

Comment: Your `git remotes` suggests that the push would go back to `PPBDS/primer`, which I'm inferring you do not have permission to push to. I'm not good with `usethis::` github-related functions, sorry, but I'm guessing that the `fork=TRUE` did not set the remotes as I would infer it to do. Specifically, the docs say that it should have set up an `"upstream"` remote, and it appears that not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `git remotes` shows that the repo was cloned over `https` (no push allowed over https) and no fork was configured.

If I'm interpreting you correctly, the output *should* be:

```
origin git@github.com:AtillaColak/primer.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:AtillaColak/primer.git (push)
upstream https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.git (push)
```

Perhaps this will work? (Untested) (in a shell, not in R)

```sh
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin git@github.com:AtillaColak/primer.git
```

If those commands do not work, the `.git/config` file should look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:AtillaColak/primer.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "upstream"]
        url = https://github.com/PPBDS/primer.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

I don't encourage editing the `.git/config` file manually if you can avoid it, but this (if nothing else) may provide verification of other attempts.